# How can i reset my document.getElementById color value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the color from red to blue but when the red color come its unchangeable

```
var colorvalue=0;
var sizevalue;
function CG()
{
    colorvalue ++;
    if (colorvalue==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("testd").style.color = "blue";
    }
    else if(colorvalue==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("testd").style.color = "red";
    }
    if(colorvalue > 1)
    {
        colorvalue = 0;
    }
}
```

I already got the answer but how do i have more colors

Thanks for seeing my question and if you do thanks for answering

Comment: Try to dry run the code yourself and you would know why. You set `colorvalue` to `0` at the end, then increment `colorvalue` at the beginning of next call. Therefore `colorvalue` has already become `1` when the code reaches `colorvalue==0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method would be to use CSS rather than setting the style directly on the element using JavaScript.

Initialise your text with the color red, and then [toggle a blue class on/off using `classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.test');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  test.classList.toggle('blue');
}
```

```css
.test { color: red; }
.blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p class="test">This is a test</p>
<button>Change color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

i edit a bit of your code. try below

```
var colorvalue=0;
var sizevalue;
function CG()
{
    colorvalue ++;
    if (colorvalue % 2 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("testd").style.color = "blue";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("testd").style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

Used modulo operation: So if there is a remainder of **colorvalue**, element will be red.

Comment: Thanks This helped me im new so i cant upvote your answer but i dunno that we can do that in javascript thanks